# Reload a @property-decorated method of object

Tags: python, oop, properties, overloading

Warning: that's not a real-use production code, it's just a try to dig deeper into Python's inner structure!
Say, I have such (slightly PHP-styled) class in my Python code:

```
class Person:
     _age: int
     def __init__(self, age): self.setAge(age)
     def getAge(self): return self._age
     def setAge(self, age): self._age = age
     def hello(self): print(f"Hello, I'm {self.getAge()}")
```

Now I create some objects of Person:

```
tom = Person(20)
betty = Person(22)
john = Person(30)
john.hello()  # output: "Hello, I'm 30"
```

Now let's assume that John has some reasons to conceal his real age, so we do dirty trick by reloading his getAge:

```
john.getAge = lambda: john._age - 5
john.hello()  # output: "Hello, I'm 25"
```

Do we have some ways to do this if Person is declared in more Pythonic way using @property?

```
class Person:
     _age: int
     def __init__(self, age): self._age = age

     @property
     def age(self): return self._age

     @age.setter
     def age(self, x): self._age = x

     def hello(self): print(f"Hello, I'm {self.age}")
```